# Python test if list items are far apart

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a list in python that might look something like this:

```
list_example = [1,2,20,21,22]
```

As you can see, all the numbers are close to their adjacent list items, except for the jump between 2 and 20.

How would I get Python to notice this larger jump and store the list item's index?

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate through every `i` and `i+1` element, and then compute the difference between the two adjacent elements.

```
for a, b in zip(list_example, list_example[1:]):
    diff = b - a
    if diff > 10:
        print("Jump between %d and %d" % (a, b))
```

But then, it is up to you to define what is exactly a "jump".

If you need the index, you can make use of [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(list_example, list_example[1:])):
    ...
```

Comment: You solution however assume non-decreasing ordering. It would fail for a [10,11,2,5,6,7].

Comment: @Aechlys Indeed, I asumed the list was sorted based on the author example. The author must adapt the `diff` calculation according to his use case that he is the only one to know, he may use `abs(b - a)` for example.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the average distance between elements and then output those indices where the distance to the last element is larger than that average.

```
>>> lst = [1,2,20,21,22]
>>> avg_dst = sum(abs(a-b) for a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:])) / (len(lst)-1)
>>> [i for i in range(1, len(lst)) if abs(lst[i] - lst[i-1]) > avg_dst]
[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a set number that is the number that will set a jump off.
This means looping over comparing the current number with its neighbour and alerting whenever the numbers have a difference of your set jump number.

This is assuming your list is already sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the values are arranged in ascending order (like your example), you could created a sorted list of `(DIFF, INDEX)` pairs.

```
xs = [1, 2, 20, 21, 22]
pairs = sorted((xs[i] - xs[i-1], i) for i in range(1, len(xs)))

print(pairs)  # [(1, 1), (1, 3), (1, 4), (18, 2)]
```